# Find hamming distance between two Strings of equal length in Java

Tags: java, performance, strings, array, edit-distance

I have a private class that I want to be able to find the shortest Hamming Distance between two Strings of equal length in Java. The private class holds a `char[]` and contains a method to compare against other char arrays. It returns true if there is only a hamming distance of one.

The average length of the Strings used is 9 characters. They range from 1 to 24 characters.

Is there a way to make the `isDistanceOne(char[])` method go any faster?

```
private class WordArray {

  char[] word;

  /**
   * Creates a new WordArray object.
   *
   * @param word The word to add to the WordArray.
   */
  private WordArray(String word) {
     this.word = word.toCharArray();
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether the argument is within a Hamming Distance of one from
   * the char[] contained in the WordArray.
   *
   * Both char[]s should be of the same length.
   *
   * @param otherWord The word to compare with this.word.
   * @return boolean.
   */
  private boolean isDistanceOne(char[] otherWord) {

     int count = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < otherWord.length; i++) {
        if (this.word[i] != otherWord[i])
           count++;
     }

     return (count == 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: How large are the Strings? The fastest solution would differ for many short Strings versus very large strings

Comment: @dustytrash The range is from 1 to 24. The average length is 9. I've edited my question to mention this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the limited context, and no information about where the hotspot is in the code, it's difficult to give concrete advice. Here are some musings for your consideration:

For ease of reading, it's preferable to have whitespace after control flow keywords and before the `(`.

It is suggested to always include curly braces, even when they're not required by the compiler.

Use `final` where possible to reduce cognitive load on the readers of your code.

`word` should be private.

There's no apparent reason to use `char[]` instead of just keeping a pointer to the original `String`. They're costing you time and space to make, to no benefit.

You can short-circuit out of your `for` loop if the count ever becomes greater than one. Unless a significant fraction of your inputs have a distance of one, you should see some performance gain here.

Using a `boolean` instead of an `int` *might* make a very small difference in execution time, but that would need to be tested. It also makes the code harder to read.

```
private class WordArray {

    private final String word;

    private WordArray(final String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    private boolean isDistanceOne(final char[] otherWord) {
        assert word.length() == otherWord.length;

        int distance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < otherWord.length; i++) {
            if (this.word.charAt(i) == otherWord[i]) {
                continue;
            }

            if (distance > 0) {
                return false;
            }

            distance++;
        }


        return distance == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can beat that linear complexity since you need to look at each character to determine the Hamming distance.

One small optimization you can do is to short-circuit once your count goes above one, but that adds an extra check in every iteration, so it might have worse runtime depending on the inputs.